# Meaning of Stack[0x4]:1

Tags: assembly, ghidra

So I have encounter something strange that I don't understand. I am reading theory about assembly, and I would like to know what does this Stack[0x4]:1 do.

```
undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>                                XREF[2]:     00010807(W),
                                                                                                   00010869(W)  
             undefined1        Stack[0x4]:1   param_1                                 XREF[1]:     00010779(*)
```

I dont understand it because the article says that this is -0x43, and by the way what does that - do in -0x43?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I believe I didn't understand this part:```Stack[0x04] would represent parameter 1 (param_1)on the stack (each parameter is 4 bytes wide).I believe the :1 means that param_1 is a byte``` are you saying that 0x4 is stored/represented by 1 byte and there is 4 of them? And also is -0x43 just because it is local variable?

Comment: Could you perhaps add more information about the article you are referring to here?

Comment: Any chance you are looking at: https://guyinatuxedo.github.io/04-bof_variable/tamu19_pwn1/index.html ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer and yes I am refering to that article.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing `param_1` with `input`. Those are different things. `param_1` since it's in `main` function would be renamed as `argc`. `input` is a buffer allocated on the stack that will be filled later with a call to `gets`.

`param_1`'s since it's a parameter (in this ABI) be at positive offset from `ESP` - in this case `0x4` and `input` since it's local variable will be at negative offset from `ESP` in this case `-0x43`. This is due to the fact that stack grows towards lower addresses.

Back to Ghidra, `Stack[0x4]:1` means that this parameter's value is passed via stack and the value is at offset `0x4` and Ghidra has identified that it's probably of a size of 1 byte.